# grails ehcache - no configuration found

Tags: grails-3.3, ehcache-3

Grails 3.3.1
ehcache 3.0.0.M1

Since I am not able to create properly running caches programmatically, I try to create it via xml. But I don't know where to put the file. Every time I start the application the log output is like this:

> 2018-07-02 12:21:21.168  WARN --- [           main] n.s.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory  : No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/2.10.4/9022b1eedfafa11039597b1c1918c1abe414df93/ehcache-2.10.4.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml

these are my yml settings:

```
grails:
    cache:
        ehcache:
            ehcacheXmlLocation: 'classpath:ehcacheCustom.xml'
            lockTimeout: 200
```

So in which folder should I put my `ehcacheCustom.xml`?

Thanks for suggestions or working examples

Comment: solution: i put the xml file into grails-app/conf and my yml config was like this: `grails:
    cache:
        ehcache:
            ehcacheXmlLocation: 'ehcacheCustom.xml'
            lockTimeout: 200`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the xml file into `grails-app/conf/ehcacheCustom.xml` and my application.yml was like this:

`grails:
    cache:
        ehcache:
            ehcacheXmlLocation: 'ehcacheCustom.xml'
            lockTimeout: 200`